# Mongoose pre-save binding/this keyword is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, this

**Schema Definition**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var person = new Schema({
    name: {type : String}
})

person.pre('save', (next) => {
    console.log('in pre function and')
    console.log("this.name ",this.name);
    if (this.name == ' ') {
       // throw new console.error(' in valid name');
        console.log(err);
    }

    if (this.isNew == 'true') {
        console.log(this);
    } else {
        console.log(' false ' , this)
    }
    next();
})

const personModel = mongoose.model('personTable', person);
module.exports = {
    personModel
}
```

**DataBase**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const {personModel} = require('./schema');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dataBase',{useNewUrlParser : true});
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open',()=>{
    console.log(' Connection successful ');

    const prakash = new personModel({
        name : 'prakash'
    })

    
    prakash.save((err,data)=>{
        if(err)console.error(err);
        else console.log('data saved ',data);
    })
})
```

In the Schema definition file, when I am logging out `this.name` and it is giving `undefined`
I could not understand this behavior, I have gone through [this site](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/mongoose/Schema/pre) and followed it but still couldn't find the way to recognize the error.

Comment: If my answer was helpful or provide a suggested information, please up vote it, (or down-vote, if it doesn't) and close the question, by accepting an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing wrong with `mongo` or `mongoose`, it's arrow function declaration.

Check the [link that you have already posted](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/mongoose/Schema/pre). There is `function` keyword everywhere in examples.

Just follow the examples that you have provided via this code:

```
Schema.pre('save', function (next) {...
```

and you will get the following

You might wanna take a look at this questions on StackOverflow:

- [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable/34361380#34361380)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440)

Also, MDN [this MDN link about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).